# Generate DTOs from Object

Tags: visual-studio-2008, code-generation, devexpress, resharper, vsx

I want to auto gen some DTOs from some of my existing objects, I was wondering if there already exist a Resharper, DevExpress or VSX open source to use, I need a tool to look into my code and let me choose which properties I want to include in my DTO and then generate a class based on that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is kind of a hack but you could use Visual Studio/Resharper to Extract an interface from the class, then create a DTO class and derive from the interface, then use Visual Studio to auto implement the interface members (then, optionally remove the interface).

Comment: Interesting approach, but I could also copy the class and remove not wanted elements. I was after a clean and fast way of doing it over and over again...

Answer (score 7):

Another opinion would be to use some reflection code in a T4 template.

T4 templates are one of the powerful hidden features of Visual Studio.

Take a look [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/03/03/tip-3-getting-started-with-t4.aspx) to see how easy it is to get started with T4.

Comment: It must have been an intermittent failure, its working again.