# How can I clone (generate code) all fields of one class into another?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am writing a WCF service and I want to use DataTransferObjects that basically clone all fields of my classes.
For example I have a class `Person`

```
class Person
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public Person()
    {
        //Some complex stuff here
    }
}

class PersonDTO
{
    //Copy all public fields and properties of Person
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
}
```

Is there a way to generate my DTO class based on other class? A code-snippet or something like that?

I am not trying to copy the values of the fields. I want to generate a class with same fields as the "Parent" class. But I don't want to inherit my DTO class

Comment: Why don't you inherit `PersonDTO` from `Person`?

Comment: Because I don't want `PersonDTO` changed if `Person` gets changed

Comment: Yeah, but inheritance will just get the members, properties, and functions in the child class. The values that the members and properties hold will not be copied.

Comment: You are looking for a code generator. Sounds like a job for visual studio macro. Are you gonna use library in mapping between DTO and business object?

Comment: @Mino, yes, I am looking for a code generator (and I stated it in the question), the question is - which code generator should I use (and how).

Comment: There is one sort of answer for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832578/generate-dtos-from-object

Comment: @Mino, there is a dirty hack which I will use. Thank you )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use T4 templates to generate DTOs from your entities. Here is article [Code generation with T4, Entities to DTOs example](http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2009/03/11/code-generation-with-t4-an-entities-to-dto-example.aspx) which have sample project attached for generating DTOs from entities.

Main idea is providing path to assembly with entities:

```
var entitiesAssembly = @"bin\Debug\EntitiesToDTO.dll";
```

Then getting all entity types from that assembly:

```
var typesToRegister = 
    from t in LoadProjectAssembly(entitiesAssembly).GetExportedTypes()
    where t.Namespace == entitiesNamespace && t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract
    select t;
```

And processing them in a loop:

```
<#
foreach (var type in typesToRegister.Where(t => t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract))
{#>
   [DataContract(Name="<#= ConvertToCamelCase(type.Name) #>]
   public partial class <#= GetDTOClassName(type.Name) #>
   {
      <# foreach (var property in type.GetProperties())
      {#>
         // analyze property type
         // and generate appropriate DataMember property
      <#}#>
   }
<#}#>
```

Comment: Do you get the Assembly from an static path in **LoadProjectAssembly**?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [T4 templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx), that will help you to generate code. It will not be that hard, but not easy too. Once you done for single class you can re-use it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me that what you're looking for is deep cloning.
You basically serialize the object you want to copy, then deserialize the result.

Take a look here: [Deep cloning objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Not really. I have EF classes which I don't want to expose via WCF, and I want to create DTO objects which have less firlds, and they will be exposed via WCF contract.